# Udp transmit packet lost on linux embedded device (GigE Vision camera) in rare cases

Tags: c, linux, sockets, embedded

Hardware:

- derived from Sequoia-Platform (AMCC)
- Using AMCC PowerPC 440EPx and
- Marvell 88E1111 Ethernet PHY, 256 M DDR2 RAM
- Linux version 2.6.24.2

I transmit data via udp socket ca. 60MB per second in a linux-application (C –Language). Sometimes my PC-Test program notice a **lost packet** because all packets are numbered (GigE Vision Stream Channel protocol) I Know that the UDP-protocol is unreliable. But because I have **clean labor conditions** and it **always the same last packet** which is lost, I think it must be a **systematic error** somewhere in my code.

---

So I try to find out the cause of the missing packet over a week but I can’t find it.

Following issues:

- using Jumbo-Frames : packet size 8K Bytes
- always the same last packet which is lost
- error is rare (after some hours and thousands of transferred images)
- error rate is higher after a connect or reconnect the device on NIC (after Auto negotiation)

I tried :

- Use another NIC
- Check my code : check the return values of functions, check the error handling of functions
- Log the outgoing packages on my device
- View packages with wireshark tool, and check with logged
  packages from device

How I can solve the problem?
I know it is difficult because there are so many possibilities of cause of failure.

Questions:

- Are there any know bugs on linux 2.6.24 ethernet driver stack(
  especially after Auto negotiation)  which were fixed in later
  versions?
- Should I set special options on my transfer socket ? (sock
  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
- Should I renew the socket after Auto negotiation ?
- Should I enable any linux diagnostic messages in linux kernel to find out what is going wrong ?
- Are there other recommendations ?

Comment: *Last* packet? Do you [`shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) the socket after sending the last packet, but before `close(fd);`?

Comment: If the UDP packets are sequentially numbered, why not keep track of the packets, and ask the sender to resend a missing packet? At 60 MiB/s and 8k per packet, you have a data rate of 7680 packets/second. Having the sender keep copies of the last 8192 packets or so takes only 64 MiB extra. The receiver needs to keep a tally of the received packets, so that UDP packet reordering is not an issue. Do you need example code?

Comment: I would try to shutdown the socket after last packet. But how can I continue with next image? Can I do this without close and re-open the socket ?

Comment: No, `shutdown()` is permanent; you would need to close and re-open the socket. However, since you intend to continue with the next image, it means the packet was *not* the last one; just a particular one. I bet that either the missing packet was not actually the final one of the image, that you only notice it missing when trying to receive the final one for a particular image, that packet having some identifying feature; or that all images are the same size, and it's just a coincidence, maybe a timing issue. If the packets do have unique sequence numbers, do you check *which* one is missing?

Comment: Yes you are right. Let me explain the packet order in an example of 2048 x 2048 Byte image and a Packet Size of 8192. Every image was transmitting as follow:
• Packet Id 0 : so called “header” 40 Bytes 
• Packet Id 1 ..514 : 8192 Byte (8156 Byte Image Data + protocol overhead)
• Packet Id 515 : 2136 Byte (2120 Byte Image Data + protocol overhead)
• Packet Id 516 so called “Leader” 16 Bytes. 
The Packet Id 515 in this example is sometimes missing. 
But I have observed if the packet Size is 8228 all the Data Packets have the same size and the packet loss is more rarely

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar problems on an application I once developed where one side of the connection was windows, and the other side was an embedded real time OS (not linux) and the only thing in between was cat5 ethernet cable. Indeed I found that a certain flury of UDP messages would almost always cause 1 of the messages to be lost, and it was always the same message. Very strange, and after a lot of time with wireshark and other network tools I finally decided that it could only be the fact that UDP was unreliable.

My advice is to switch to TCP and build a small message framer:

http://blog.chrisd.info/tcp-message-framing/

I find using TCP to be very reliable, and it can also be very fast if the traffic is "stream like" (meaning: mostly unidirectional) additionally building a message framer on top of TCP is much easier than building TCP on top of UDP.

Comment: You are right. But TCP is no option for me. Because of the GigE Vision standard I must use the unreliable UDP.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that it's the camera's fault - surprisingly even on the camera side, GigE vision can be more complicated and less deterministic than competing technologies like CameraLink.  In particular I've seen my own strange problems and have been told from manufacturers that many of the cameras have some known buffering issues, in particular when running at their higher resolution/framerates.

Check your camera's firmware with the vendor and see if there's an update to address this.

Alternatively perhaps you have some delay between the last packet recvmsg and the previous recvmsg such as processing the frame data before receiving the end of the gvsp frame packet?

Additional recommendation: make sure no switch or other networking equipment is in the middle between the system and the camera - use a direct Cat-6e cable.